# My vba code does not seem to work, even though there are no errors

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through all cells in a specified range and replace two different parts of the function in the cell.

However, the code seems to run, and when I put a msgbox LastCol, it returns me the last cell in the row, but the function does not change.

Code:

```
Sub Function1()

 Dim LastCol As Integer
 Dim i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


    For i = 1 To LastCol

     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("D3" & i).Replace "4. Apr", "5. May", xlPart
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("D3" & i).Replace "April", "May", xlPart


    Next i


End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i was 1 then Range("D3" & i) refers to D31. Try,

```
 with ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
     .Range(.cells(3, "D"), .cells(3, LastCol)).Replace What:="4. Apr", replacement:="5. May", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=false
     .Range(.cells(3, "D"), .cells(3, LastCol)).Replace What:="April", replacement:="May", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=false
 end with
```

tbh, it's not at all clear what you mean by 'specified range'.

Comment: Wow, thanks! that worked like magic! Haha thanks a bunch, working perfctly now.